# Where does End Clip Distance start on Orthographic view?

Tags: 3d-view

In Orthographic view the [Start Clip setting has no effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/why-does-the-3d-viewports-start-clip-have-no-effect-in-ortho-view). If I move the End clip it will affect both front and back clipping on the scene.

[image]

Setting the end clip to 1m (as I prefer working in metric scale) will show me a sliver of my scene that is only 1 meter deep, (determined by the clip distance). My question is this: that 1 meter distance seems quite arbitrary: 1 meter from where? X:0, Y:0 Z:0? How is the center of that visible range determined?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's defined by the *View pivot*. The view [orbits around a single point](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/651/599) which is moved by a variety of actions (e.g. panning with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> or zooming to an object with <kbd>numpad .</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: merci beaucoup!

Comment: @cegaton please keep your comment and answers to English on this site :) </joke> PS translation "Thank you very much."

Comment: This does not solve the clipping issue in the question