# model shows semitransparent in vewport

Tags: modeling, interface, faces

this are the similar post that i post on

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50027/blender-face-problem-on-large-file

i got this wire-face problem

[image]

and i think the problem solved

it is a camera clipping for sure.

thank you coco knight, mr  Zak, rick riggs.

thank you all of you guys.

thank you

[image]

Comment: What "problem" do you have exactly ? Do you mean edges can be seen through ? Do you mean the model has undesired new face appeared ? Please specify what is the problem other than only file.

Comment: I'm not at my computer to look at this blend, but my gut says viewport clipping, or if that is really the geometry, try hitting the `Tab` key and let us know if that solves the problem. Based on your next post though it looks like you just need to go into face mode (three buttons from the right of where it says global right above the timeline)

Comment: i just hit tab and it switch to object mode only. the problem remain the same. thank you

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40190/where-does-end-clip-distance-start-on-orthographic-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what the issue is. When 3D View is set to Ortho and view clip end is set to 100000 or bigger, then evetything is drawn as if limit selection to visible was not ticked. You get the same weird effect (also on perspective view), when view clip start is set to 0.01 or less. I hate it when that happens. The only workaround I've come up with over the years is to work at scales that work well in blender, and change scales on export if needed.

Comment: So do u have any example or guideline i can search for it? thank you

Comment: what do you mean? make sure your view clipping range is in between 0.1 and 10000. Scale your models accordingly.