# How do I setup my camera to render the same as my viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

When I look through my camera view (or render a frame) it comes out with my wireframe lines being fuzzy and broken up (see below).  While I am trying to fix this specific issue, my real question is **how do I get my camera settings to match my viewport settings exactly?**.  This would not only solve my current issue, but also give me a good baseline for any future issues I may have with my camera view differing from my modeling viewport view.

Link to file (blend-exchange isn't working for me): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y5AtarYjf2TkihQOOop6TNCsBjh_ciJV/view?usp=sharing

Viewport -> Rendered

[image]

Viewport -> Rendered -> Camera
[image]

Comment: The artifacts that you are faced, called z-fighting. You can fix that by copy clip start and end settings from viewport to camera.

Comment: It is a clipping distance issue, but I wouldn't copy the settings from the viewport as it doesn't have the same needs as the camera to begin with, and both can be set wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

When you see geometry being disrupted this way, and it being different in and out of camera, you know it is a clipping distance issue:

[image]

This is the kind of z-fighting you get when the start/end distance are too far appart to be precise. And the fact that it's not looking the same in and out of camera is because the viewport and camera each have their own clipping settings but don't use the same distances by default. If we look at your camera settings, we see that you set your End distance to 50 thousand kilometers, while your start distance is 0.1 km:

[image]

Two issues here:

- You don't need to render all the way down to 50km afar, 20 is enough in your case
- When you change either of these values, you should change the other value as well so that the gap remains roughly as small as possible. I put it to 5km in your case.

Further reading to understand why it works this way:

- [Rendering artifacts in blender internal - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23672/rendering-artifacts-in-blender-internal/23693#23693)
- [edit mode - Why does the 3D view have trouble with clip start <=0.01 - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50066/why-does-the-3d-view-have-trouble-with-clip-start-0-01/50068#50068)

Comment: Thank you for solving this!  Are there any other common issues you know of where the camera view and modeling view differ so much?  I'd really like to lock down my camera to a known baseline so I can work outwards from there.

Comment: AFAIK the only settings that differs by default is the Focal Length (FOV) and whether you are in perspective or orthographic. These are the only settings of the viewport's camera you have access to. But for any camera object, you can change way more settings, so you can get wildly different results if you change your camera settings drastically.