# Flickering and funky cameracontrolls in perspective-view

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

I am having craphical glitches in one Blenderproject.  But only when switching to "User persp" View.
I was working in orthographic view for some time, so i can not tell when this happened.

Additionaly to the flickering Holes in the Mesh, manuvering the camera gets all funky and i can no longer place the 3D-cursor against the background.

Thank you for your attention.

2 Pictures to show the difference between orthographic and perspective:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks to me like Z fighting. See if there are two objects there, or duplicated mesh data.

Comment: Try increasing Start Clip value in Properties shelf panel > View rollout. Maybe like http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/why-does-the-3d-viewports-start-clip-have-no-effect-in-ortho-view

Comment: May actually also be caused by the opposite: too far apart clipping values causing precision issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and thank you very much for your comments!

The problem was indeed "Clip: Start". As soon as i changed the value all problems were gone. Visuals and controlls restored to normal.
But this must have been a bug, since i could not reproduce the problem by setting the value back to 0.001.

I hope some people can use this workaround in case they run into the same glitch.

Thank you for your Help!